# Identity proceeds as normal, but with a leading 10...?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity

So I noticed a very strange thing when tinkering with my database.

I had just inserted a row which was ID 47, then after inserting some more, I realised that somehow my Identity had skipped all the way to 146, so it had skipped 999 to get there.

It's not a huge problem, or a gamestopper, just very strange, **is there any way I can solve this?** Short of backing up the data and recreating the table.

For the record, I didn't do anything at all between the data insertion - it seems to be totally random (of course it's not, something caused it I'm sure...)

[image: Screenshot of strange data]

Comment: While this isn't exactly expected behavior, do you care enough about gaps that this needs to be "solved"? If you need to avoid gaps, as @gbn implied, you shouldn't be using IDENTITY because there is no way to prevent gaps.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known behaviour difference in SQL Server 2012 because of a change in the way `IDENTITY` is implemented.

See [related Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity) for some discussion and possible workarounds (if this is a real issue for you)

Answer (score 5):

IDENTITY sequences will **never** be contiguous

- failed (and rolled back) INSERTs will increment
- rows can be deleted
- DBCC CHECKIDENT could have been run
- See [Do Inserted Records Always Receive Contiguous Identity Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4219201/27535) on SO too

Row deletion is quite important if you have history/audit tables: you'd never want to reuse an ID that exists in some history/audit table somewhere of course